# Hadoop grep dump sql

Tags: hadoop

I want to use Apache Hadoop to parse large files (~~ 20 MB each). These files are postegresql dumps (i.e. mostly CREATE TABLE and INSERT). I just need to filter out anything that is not CREATE TABLE or INSERT INTO in the first place.

So I decided to use the grep map reduce with `^(CREATE TABLE|INSERT).*;$` pattern (lines starting with CREATE TABLE or INSERT and ending with a ";").
My problem is some of these create and insert take multiple lines (because the schema is really large I guess) so the pattern isn't able to match them at all (like `CREATE TABLE test(\n
"id"....\n..."name"...\n
);`)

I guess I could write a mapreduce job to refactor each "insert" and "create" on one line but that would be really costly because the files are large. I could also remove all "\n" from the file but then a single map operation would have to handle multiple create/insert making the balance of the work really bad. I'd really like one map operation per insert or create.

I'm not responsible for the creation of the dump files so I cannot change the layout of the initial dump files.

I have actually no clue what is the best solution, I could use some help :). I can provide any additionnal information if needed.

Comment: How about this regex to extract all the valid lines https://regex101.com/r/myrLaA/1? Note: without a sample data it is pretty hard to provide you a good answer.

Comment: Sorry I was not really clear about the real issue. The regexp is ok, I just had trouble to understand Hadoop map mechanics. I used the grep mapreduce example from Hadoop (https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Grep) to begin work but the map operation of this example is a line per line function so I had no way to  retrieve the full SQL line.Instead I will just write the mapper and make it handle the whole file instead of using the standard grep one. Thx for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first:
**20 mb files are NOT large files to Hadoop standards**, you will probably have many files (unless you only have a tiny amount of data) so there should be plenty of parallelization possible.

As such having 1 mapper per file could very well be an excellent solution, and you may even want to concatenate files to reduce overhead.

---

That being said:

If you don't want to handle all lines at once, and handling a single line at once is insufficient, then the only straightforward solution would be to handle 'a few' lines at once, for example 2 or 3.

An alternate solution would be to chop the file up and use one map per filepart, but then you either need to deal with the edges, or accept that your solution may not remove one of the desired bits.

I realize that this is still quite a conceptual answer, but based on your progress so far, I feel that this may be sufficient to get you there.

Comment: That is quite the answer I was looking for actually !  As you mentioned 20 MB text file isn't huge at all for Hadoop, and I have enough files (about 500 files now, will probably grow in the future) to get through the parallelization that I need. It would just increase the overhead to split the file into many map operations rather than mapping it once. Again as you said I'm more likely to end up concatenating my files rather than splitting each file before starting the map operations.Your alternative solutions helped me understanding the problem as well. Thx a lot for the answer.